# How to decrypt magento community edition password?

Tags: magento-1.9, password, magento-1.9.4.0

I am storing customer info using observer and need to store password in plain text.

Comment: no, you dont need to :)

Comment: Please can you add more detail on why you need to do this?

Comment: i want to retrieve original customer password,

Comment: you should never store a password in plain text it is a stupid idea. the only time you have access to the customer's plain text password is immediately when they submit it using the registration or checkout form. Magento actually uses it to send to the customer in an email, unencrypted, which itself is seen as bad practice

Comment: thanks now i am storing password at customer registration and update.